# Who is the game character I'm thinking of?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, video-games

I ask you to find a video game character.

> He takes care of BB
>
> gamgee
>
> mysterious soldier

Who is it?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**) I'm glad you're eager to contribute a puzzle here, but I fear this one may not fare well. It's more of a trivia question (something you recognize) than a riddle (something you have to work through somewhat obscured clues to figure out), and those don't make for very interesting puzzles. You may benefit from looking around the site, and in particular checking out high voted puzzles in the tags that appeal to you, to get a better sense of what kinds of things work best here. Welcome again, and hope your next puzzle sees great success!

Comment: Thanks for advise you give!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly

> Sam Porter Bridges from *Death Stranding*

> He takes care of BB

> Caring for a mysterious infant called BB is one of Bridges' primary goals in the game.

> gamgee

> I presume this refers to the *Lord of the Rings* character with the same first name as Bridges: Sam.

> mysterious soldier

> *Death Stranding* does indeed feature mysterious soldiers, including a guy played by Mads Mikkelsen.

I'm not familiar enough with the game to elaborate on the last point, but the other two points fit so well that I'm fairly confident I'm right.

Comment: Thanks, You are awesome!

Comment: If an answer is correct or otherwise helpful, you can upvote it by clicking the up arrow next to it, and accept it by clicking the green tick mark.

Comment: Thanks again my friend!

Comment: i'am new here, so much to learn before becoming expert haha